# My Website title changes by itself in Google

Tags: seo, google, meta-tags, local-seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Title tag different from title appearing in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/title-tag-different-from-title-appearing-in-google)

I am doing seo on my friends site and each page has its own metas it did change to new ones then somehow google is taking company name as the meta title I just googled this topic and last few days other people getting same problem , I had similar issue in the past on my own site that soon changed after changing the metas again any seo experts with same problem please help , there is no h1 heading on the company name or alt tag with that also.

Comment: Also if you go to the site index you can see that it's displaying meta title correct their but in google it's company name also I just noticed its doing on other pages also, I don't really want to remove company name everywhere, and I don't understand why google thinks the company name is relevant to search results

Comment: Also that snippet you showed me the letters are all capitals the result in google shows the first letters in company name are capital then lower case , Do you think it's the footer next to the copyright ?? if you do check in google type site:svipl.in there you will see the repeat results where google makes own meta titles

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the meta-title tag, so Google has can't use it as a signal for to what to use for the title. It looks like in your case it is pulling from the  tag lower down on the page and using that as the title.

```
<h2 class="about-head"><span>ABOUT</span> SIDDHIVINAYAK INFOCOM PVT. LTD.</h2>
```

My advice, either add a meta title, or add an appropriate h1 heading.

Also, the meta-description is pretty spammy, I would change that to a human readable paragraph about your company rather than just keyword stuffing in it.

Comment: Hi Johnathan , thanks for reply , I am using meta title if you view page source, yes I think your right about where it's pulling the meta title choice from near footer , the weird thing is it was reading new meta title about one week ago then changed to company name, this happened as I said about one year ago on my own websites, I'm sure it's a google testing of penguin updates so strange also that some of my other sites are now back on page one in google , as I had to repeat keyword twice in meta title as that seems to work on the seo targeting I do only do white hat seo, thanks Jde