# How long does it take for Google to re-index pages or update the link titles?

Tags: google-search, title, sitelinks

On one of our classified sites, when doing `site:[mysite.com]` in Google, the link text is simply *[product name] - [mysite.com]*, where as it should read *[product name]* classifieds for sale in...

I suspect that the site map may have been submitted when we just had *[product name]*, and updated the page titles later.  However, it has been a couple of weeks that I have confirmed the longer page titles, and still they appear shortened in organic results.

How can I get this looking right in Google's organic results?

Comment: The title that Google shows in the SERPs is dynamic. It is dependent on what is being searched for and does not necessarily reflect the actual title of the page. See also: [Title tag different from title appearing in Google?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/title-tag-different-from-title-appearing-in-google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a variable amount of time. Pages on this website are updated quickly while pages on "smaller" sites can take weeks or months. This is due to several factors including link popularity, frequency of new content, and more.

Basically the only thing you can do is continue to update your website and seek quality links to it. That will help but how long it takes is out of your control, really.

Comment: If you specify in the sitemap that the page changes frequently, would that help? I recently changed a lot of stuff as titles and meta tags in of of my websites, and immediately (next day) google had indexed about 600 extra pages. It didn't change the title when displayed in organic searches, which is the question, but google definitely noticed the difference in the pages, since it indexed almost all of them.

Answer (score 2):

It depends hugely on how quickly Google deals with the updated information.

**For example:** I specified on my sitemap that my site changes daily and i posted a topic on my site but it doesn't appear on the search results even when i included my sites whole name on the query.

After 3 days it appeared on Google so i changed the title of my topic and after 3 days again it showed my new title.

**Google updates can take 1min or 4 weeks and even longer**

You shouldn't concern yourself to much the fact Google hasn't updated the page information, looking at the results will not speed them up and much more construction action can be taken. Updating the other pages will make Google treat your site more seriously and return, update results more quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working as blogger since 2010.  When I have changed a few words on my existing pages, it takes Google 2-3 days to index all those changes.