# Google search results show my title incorrectly twice

Tags: seo, google-search, magento, title

Does anyone know why Google shows my title twice in search results? And it's the wrong title too.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: See the following related question:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/title-tag-different-from-title-appearing-in-google  The difference between that question and this one is that the _domain_ (not necessarily brand) is being displayed twice. Also, the text in the source code was in another language (Danish).

Answer (score 2):

It seems Google wasn't able to create a title from the Danish inside your `title` tag, so used the contents of your `H1` tag, which matches the title that Google displayed instead.

*(Note that the contents of the H1 tag were edited out of this answer - see version number 1 of this answer for more details.)*

You might consider supplying a title in English when submitting to `google.com`, and developing [multilingual](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en) versions of your site if you haven't already.

Comment: Google can careate danish titles normally, there are thousands of website got their titles in danish without any problem.

Comment: In `google.com` or `google.dk`? You do have a `title` tag (in Danish), so it should have used that if it could, but seems to have used the next available content above instead.