# How to deal with product pages that require hundreds of keywords

Tags: seo, title

I am having difficulties trying to achieve SEO friendly solution of following for product pages that contain a lot of keywords. The online shop sells many parts that fit dozens different manufactures and hundreds of different models.

How do you deal with pages that contain a lot of keywords? Google is certainly going to have problems with a enormous `<title>` with all the keywords we need?

Comment: Hi @Svobol13 I've simplified your question and made it more generic so it would help other users.  Also, I've removed the focus from the `<title>` tag as your issue is beyond using just a large title tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is not a easy fix. Google uses dozens of signals to establish what your page is about, not having the actual keywords embedded on the page will result in poor rankings or no rankings for that keyword.

So, what's the fix?

Solution one...

This solution is favored by many SEO thinkers is to create dozens to hundreds of pages with the same product but with different keywords, but all will need different descriptions as you most likely would get hit by Google for duplicate content, so this is another issue. The problem with this solution is its very time consuming to make those pages and in many ways will dampen the user experience if your spending less time on each page in favor of creating more content.

Solution two...

It's important to note that Google doesn't religiously use the title tag and [will often change it to match that of the users search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/14416/20604), so with this said you can focus on building a page that contains all the keywords and Google will adapt the title to what the user is searching for, assuming that you have good SEO, authority, trust and likeability from Google.

A page flooded with all keywords will generally look spammy and in the old days would receive a penalty from keyword stuffing, lucky enough Google has improved over the years and this is no longer an issue, but its important that your pages don't look spammy for your audience as this can lower your conversion, you can use simple to use solutions such as [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html) which will allow Google to see the keywords while not spoiling the page. There's many ways this can be approached.