# Google shows old domain and wrong meta-description

Tags: domains, google-search, search-results, meta-description

I need your help to solve a problem I have with the Google SERP for my site. My site is www.personalmedia.it, now if I search the keyword "personalmedia" the result is this one:

> [image: Result for "Personalmedia" shows the domain 'www.ypma.it']

You can see that the link below the title is not personalmedia.it, but ypma.it. ypma.it is the company's old site, that now has a redirect to personalmedia.it.

**Why Google is showing that URL instead of the real URL of the real site?**

Another strange thing: if I search the keyword "personal media" the result is this one:

> [image: Result for "Personalmedia" shows a different description snippet]

In this case you can see the above problem, plus another one: the highlighted text in the description is not the text that I wrote in the description metatag as shown here (which correctly appears in the above case):

> [image: The current meta-description shows different content]

The highlighted text belongs to the page, but shouldn't be the meta description what is shown in SERP?

Comment: Sorry but your question appeals to be more about your site not ranking for a keyword, this will be happening because of 'over optimisation' or too little. Additionally there is also various questions and answers regarding Google 'rewriting' titles and meta descriptions (this is very common) and just because you don't see it in the search, doesn't mean they ain't factoring it in.

Comment: @bybe you marked my question as duplicate pointing me to a question that speaks about how increase your site's position. I don't want to increase my site position, I just want that title , description and link are correct

Comment: Corrected. Please see: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/title-tag-different-from-title-appearing-in-google and for all other things please use the search. As I said there is various and questions already on Pro Webmasters regarding rankings, title changes, meta changes and so forth. If Google is changing your title and description is nothing you can do (assuming that you have correct page content), its pulling results what it thinks is a better match.